# How to delete all instances of NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an app that requires users to enter a code each time they use it. When entering a new code I need to delete all contents in Core Data. The issue I am having is I am using RestKit which allows you to use several `NSManagedContext`s (e.g. `[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]`).

Is there a way from Core Data to delete all contexts so that `AppDelegates` context is destroyed and all the contexts in there current threads?

Maybe send out a notification and anything that has a `contextForCurrentThread` it can delete itself or delete all its contents?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Do you need to delete objects in a context but you don't know how? Thanks.

Comment: The simplest thing is to delete the database file before building your Core Data stack (or letting RestKit build it for you).

Comment: No, I know how to delete NSManagedObjects.  The issue is my AppDelegate has a NSManagedObjectContext. But each viewController and sometimes each NSManagedObject class has its own NSManagedObjectContext for their own threads.  That way all my searching, updating, and deleting of NSManagedObjects doesn't happen on the main thread and slow down the UI to touch events.  I have "RESET" button that needs to wipe all NSManagedObjects from AppDelegates NSManagedObjectContext and all the NSManagedObjectContexts on all other threads. Since they all point to an objectStore, just delete the objectStore?

Comment: you can access and assign to nil the context.... are you tried that?